# Flash и PHP

Tags: flash, php

Связывают ли эти два языка? Т.е., например, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку во флеш объекте забивались бы определённые значения в mysql бд с помощью php. Если связывают, то посоветуйте какую-нибудь литературу по этому поводу, может статья какая-нибудь есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actionscript and PHP Development Tutorials

http://pelfusion.com/tutorials/actionscript-and-php-development-tutorials/

Comment: Жаль ,что на английском, спасибо.

Comment: @mctrane, в гугл по запросам actionscript LoadVars, XML - очень много инфы.

Comment: Ну ,в общем сначала нужно выучить AS, после уже смотреть связь с php